# Google Analytics Data Discrepancy when using secondary dimensions

Tags: google-analytics

When pulling the data by source/medium dimension (or any dimension) the numbers are not matching up when we run the same report without the source/medium dimension (or without any dimension).

Further we isolated the issue when we use a date range of 11/16 – 11/19; however if we run it day by day between those dates, the issue disappears.

Answer (score 1):

The problem may relate to **data sampling**: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2637192?hl=en

You have almost certainly passed sampling thresholds. Default reports are not subject to sampling but ad-hoc queries of your data (i.e. adding secondary dimension) are subject to sampling.